# Regular expression to match anything but certain characters

Tags: regex

Is there a way to have a regular expression to match anything but certain characters? Say for example the only characters that aren't allowed is the * character. Rather than list out all possibly characters allowed in the regular expression is there anything that will say "everything not equal to * is allowed".

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: Everything but `*`: `/^[^*]+$/`

Comment: Please note that there may some pitfalls here, as some implementations interpret "character" as _"printable_ character" while others don't. So you can't be sure if the regex includes things like tabs and newlines or not, until you test.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `negated class character` that you can use by `[^]`. So, for your case you can use:

```
^[^*]+$
```

A useful debuggex graph to see this is:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You can check more about the theory on **[negated class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)**. Below you can find a quotation explaining this.

### Negated Character Classes

> Typing a caret after the opening square bracket negates the character class. The result is that the character class matches any character that is not in the character class. Unlike the dot, negated character classes also match (invisible) line break characters. If you don't want a negated character class to match line breaks, you need to include the line break characters in the class. `[^0-9\r\n]` matches any character that is not a digit or a line break.
>
> It is important to remember that a negated character class still must match a character. `q[^u]` does not mean: "*a q not followed by a u*". It means: "*a q followed by a character that is not a u*". It does not match the q in the string Iraq. It does match the `q` and the space after the `q` in `Iraq is a country`. Indeed: the space becomes part of the overall match, because it is the "*character that is not a u*" that is matched by the negated character class in the above regexp. If you want the regex to match the `q`, and only the `q`, in both strings, you need to use negative lookahead: `q(?!u)`.

Answer (score -1):

[^*]  Any single character except: *
Whenever I had to work with regular expressions I usually go to rubular.com and test my attempts. It also has some examples, pretty usefull

Answer (score -2):

[This is explained in the manual.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=regex&t=ffsb&ia=answer)

The solution is:

```
"[^*]*"
```

Comment: - this isn't a *helpful* answer.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary then flag this post and post an answer better than this

Comment: Your answer is on the right track. However, it would just be more helpful if you added some elaboration for future readers. I'd rather you take the opportunity to edit yours.